# connect watching wallet with blockchain

Tags: transactions, blockchain, bitcoinj, java

i have created watch wallet
`Wallet wallet = Wallet.fromWatchingKeyB58(params, tPub, DeterministicHierarchy.BIP32_STANDARDISATION_TIME_SECS);`
How can i link this with block chain
i am using WalletAppKit class

```
kit = new WalletAppKit(params, walletFile, APP_NAME);
kit.startAsync(); kit.awaitRunning();
```

after that i add wallet in PeerGroup `kit.peerGroup().addWallet(wallet)`
after that i print address of a wallet `System.out.println(kit.wallet().currentReceiveAddress());`
but this address and `System.out.println(wallet.currentReceiveAddress());`
this is not same.
i am using bitcoinj for this, i have sent multiple transaction on `wallet.currentReceiveAddress()`
but did not receive any of them, i don't know what i am doing wrong here, kindly help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have done this by overriding methods of WalletAppkit and its working fine now,
here is code sample for this.

```
  kit = new WalletAppKit(params, walletFile, APP_NAME) {
            @Override
            protected Wallet createWallet() {
                System.out.println("I am here");
                Wallet wallet = Wallet.fromWatchingKeyB58(params, tPub, DeterministicHierarchy.BIP32_STANDARDISATION_TIME_SECS);
                return wallet;
            }
@Override
        protected void onSetupCompleted() {
            super.onSetupCompleted();
            System.out.println(kit.wallet().currentReceiveAddress());
            System.out.println(kit.wallet().getTotalReceived().toFriendlyString());
            txHistory();

            kit.wallet().addEventListener(new AbstractWalletEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onWalletChanged(Wallet wallet) {
                    System.out.println(kit.wallet().getTotalReceived());
                }
            });
        }
```